# How to display content anywhere using html class or ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to write content in a post editor and display it somewhere in the same page only.

Previously I tried:

`<div class="post-header-title"></div>` - Where I like to display my content.

In Post Editor:

```
    <style>
        .post-header-title:after 
        {
         content:"Content that I'd like to display.";
         display: block;
         padding-top: 10px;
         font-size: 40px !important;
         color: rgb(187, 185, 185) !important;
         font-style: italic;
        }
  </style>
```

The above step using Pseudo-elements worked perfectly and it rendered the text that I want to display in my desired place.

But it can not be highlighted and search engine can not index it. So it became useless. Here is a codepen: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ggwjpj

This is just an example.

I want to do something like this.

So how can we do that? Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery has many functions to add html to your web page. To reproduce something like what you did, just use the `after` method.

```
$(".post-header-title").after("<span class='text'>SomeContent</span>");
```

See an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/yerkopalma/ghmotgub/)

Comment: Thank you very much @YerkoPalma. This completely solved my issue. You made it possible.

But this tweak doesn't work when JavaScript is disabled. I think there isn't anyway to do this thing using HTML right? Does this work like normal text or not? I mean it'd be better if search engines can crawl it. If it's just a JavaScript Search engine cannot index this text.

_Anyway this worked for me._ Thanks again **Yerko**. You are the best.

Comment: Well, I'm not pretty sure if all engines index JS. At least google does.